# Inherit variables from classes

Tags: c#

I have a problem with classes, I have an XSD schema witch I converted to classes, I have to show some value in xml document using this classes.

First I have this class:

```
namespace Transaction
{
   public partial class Header
   {
       private DateTime dateDeliveryRequestField;

        public DateTime DateDeliveryRequest
        {
            get
            {
                return this.dateDeliveryRequestField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.dateDeliveryRequestField = value;
            }
        }  
   } 

}
```

In my code I inherti this class like this

```
using Transakcija;
.
.

Transakcija.Agr3PLInventoryTransaction Agr3PL = new Transakcija.Agr3PLInventoryTransaction();

Agr3PL.DataArea.Header.DateDeliveryRequest = new DateTime();
Agr3PL.DataArea.Header.DateDeliveryRequest = SOME VALUE FROM SQL QUERY
```

And at the end I serialize  Agr3PL.DataArea.Header.DateDeliveryRequest to XMl document, but the problem is that I don't see node DateDeliveryRequest in xml document, it is not there? What am I doing wrong???

Comment: How are you serialising it out of interest? I would imagine that the problem is with that part of the process and not the setting of the variable. I assume DateDeliveryRequest was in the original schema?

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug it, step by step, and look what value DateDeliveryRequest has after:
    Agr3PL.DataArea.Header.DateDeliveryRequest = new DateTime();
and
    Agr3PL.DataArea.Header.DateDeliveryRequest = SOME VALUE FROM SQL QUERY

Comment: I did, it has a date value 01-08-2012, I extract data using sql query and I pass it to Agr3PL.DataArea.Header.DateDeliveryRequest, but after a serialization to xml document there is no node DateDeliveryRequest

Comment: Does your sql query return nullable data? If so, you should mark property of Header class with [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)] attribute.